# Why are css stylesheets reference with link?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If CSS Stylesheets are defined inline with `<style>`, then why are they referenced with `<link>`?

JavaScript uses the `<script>` tag to define inline scripts and references them with `<script src="">`, so why not use `<style src="">` for CSS? Is there a special function that the `<link>` tag can preform that using `<style>` can't?

Comment: This is not the proper place for this question. This sort of question is better suited for [chat]. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Nice question anyway! :)

Comment: It's historical.  HTML has grown piecemeal over the years, and not everything is consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of this asymmetry between `style` and `source` comes from the differences in how HTML handles scripts and resources. Javascript is (surprise!) a script, while stylesheets are considered a resource.

As we know, scripts can be both written inline or sourced out from other pages, both with that same element: `script`. This is how [the specs tells us it should work](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/scripting-1.html#script).

But also per the spec, the style element defines styling to your page, and that's all it can do. It can't reference styling from any other documents like the `script` tag can. Why? I can't say more.

A link element, on the other hand, *links* resources to your page, which can be stylesheets and other things, too. So when you're outsourcing style, you don't use `<style>` but instead you `<link>` it.

It's true that one could imagine being able to write something like `<style src=''>` where you set the source of your styling, but, alas, that attribute doesn't exist. So we can't!

Now I understand that saying "Because the specs say so" might be the most satisfying answer. But it's the best I can do for ya right now.

Source: the specs for [styles](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/semantics.html#the-style-element) and [links](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/semantics.html#the-link-element).